# Will ImgBurn -> ISO -> new DVD make an identical copy of a Windows 7 install DVD?

Tags: windows-7, backup, dvd, iso-image

I'm wanting to buy Windows 7 Ultimate but in case the DVD gets scratched I want to immediately make a backup.  What I want to be sure of is that I don't lose anything in the backup.  If, when I get the DVD, I do the following in [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/):

- Create image file from disc
- Write that image file to new DVD disc from ImgBurn

... will it create me a truly identical copy of the install DVD?  I'm planning to actually install from the newly-burnt DVD to make 100% sure it is not missing anything.  Will I lose some kind of copy-protection information in the copy process that would make the backup not work?

Also, how large a backup DVD will I need to write to?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Do you have windows license key?

Comment: If I buy Windows 7, yes I'll get the license key and install DVD.

Comment: Then you can feel free, because if you scratch DVD you can always download the same Windows 7 ISO from internet.

Comment: You can?  From where (like, legally)?

Comment: @Jez - There is a question.  Yes; Legally directly from Microsoft's digital partner.

Comment: How is this a dupe?  Copying a DVD you've bought isn't the same as downloading.

Comment: Have you tried creating an ISO and then installing in a VM?  Seems to me that'd at least indicate whether the ISO is usable.  (Scratch that:  just reread and saw you don't yet have a DVD to rip.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm figure out. You can copy a disk. Here is except from Windows 7 Ultimate license agreement:

> **10. BACKUP COPY.**
>   ***a. Media.*** 
>   If you acquired the software on a disc or other media, you may make one backup > copy  of the media. You may use it only to re-install the software on the licensed computer.
>   ***b. Electronic Download.*** 
>   If you purchased and downloaded the software online, you may make  one copy of the software on a disc or other media in order to install the software on a computer.  You may also use it to re-install the software on the licensed computer.

[Original link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/UseTerms/default.aspx).

[And it's a full license agreement for Windows 7 Ultimate from Microsoft site (PDF-file.)](http://download.microsoft.com/Documents/UseTerms/Windows_7%20Ultimate_English_6d4624d7-f664-455e-9a08-433223886d7e.pdf)

Alternativety you can download ***legal .iso*** from digitalriver. Check it out here: [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/q/78761/284998)

> Create image file from disc

- You can do that via the "Create image file from disc" button on the "Ez-Mode Picker" screen.
- Click the "Mode" menu at the top and then the "Read" option.
- Insert the source disc in the drive.
- Click the "Browse for a file" button and select a name and location for the destination image file. (Or just accept the one generated by the program)
- Click the big "Read" button.

> Write that image file to new DVD disc from ImgBurn

Just burn the .iso as it is using the "write image file to disc" option.
Make sure ImgBurn mentions "Bootable" next to where it says "File Sys" in the "Source" box once you've loaded the .iso.